# Reactjs input form for name and gender not editable

Tags: reactjs

I know this questions has been asked most often but most solution I found here does not address my issue.

The following code below displays records using reactjs. Now i have added an input form to the records in an attempt to edit **name** and **gender** but the input form is not editable at all. below is what i have tried. can someone help me with data

```
<b>Name</b>: <input type="text" className="form-control" name="name" value={obj.name}  onChange={this.handleChange} /><br />

<b>Gender</b>: <input type="text" className="form-control" name="gender" value={obj.gender}  onChange={this.handleChange} />


 handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }


    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
//process your form submission here
}
```

**here is the main code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>

   </head>
   <body>    
<script src="build/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
 this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      rec: [
        { name: "Tony", Age: "18" , gender: "male" },
        { name: "John", Age: "21" , gender: "female"},
        { name: "Luke", Age: "78" , gender: "male"},
        { name: "Mark", Age: "90" , gender: "female"},
        { name: "Jame", Age: "87" , gender: "female"},
        { name: "Franco", Age: "34" , gender: "male"},
        { name: "Franco", Age: "34" , gender: "male"},
        { name: "Biggard", Age: "19" , gender: "male"},
        { name: "tom", Age: "89" , gender: "female"}
      ],

gender: '',
name: '',

    };

  }


 handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }


    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
}




  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <div>
          <h3>Edit Records(Name and Age)</h3>





          <ul>
            {this.state.rec.map((obj, i) => (
              <li key={i}>
                {obj.name} - {obj.Age}  - {obj.gender} 

<br /><br />
<b>Name</b>: <input type="text" className="form-control" name="name" value={obj.name}  onChange={this.handleChange} /><br />

<b>Gender</b>: <input type="text" className="form-control" name="gender" value={obj.gender}  onChange={this.handleChange} />


              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));


</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


   </body>
</html>
```

**An Updated section based on Kind User solutions**

Hi Sir Kind User, your solution is really good but it still show a blank input text for name and gender as the page load though i can now input data but showing black input form makes editing record very difficult since the record is no where to be found from the inputs

here is the screenshot showing empty input records as page loads
[image]

Here is the implementation based on kind User solution/Suggestions so far

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";


import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';



class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
 this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      rec: [
        { name: "Tony", Age: "18" , gender: "male" },
        { name: "John", Age: "21" , gender: "female"},
        { name: "Luke", Age: "78" , gender: "male"},
        { name: "Mark", Age: "90" , gender: "female"},
        { name: "Jame", Age: "87" , gender: "female"},
        { name: "Franco", Age: "34" , gender: "male"},
        { name: "Franco", Age: "34" , gender: "male"},
        { name: "Biggard", Age: "19" , gender: "male"},
        { name: "tom", Age: "89" , gender: "female"}
      ],

gender: '',
name: '',

    };

  }


handleChange = (name) => (event) => {
   this.setState({ [name]: event.target.value });
}

/*
 handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }
*/

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
}




  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <div>
          <h3>Edit Records(Name and Age)</h3>





          <ul>
            {this.state.rec.map((obj, i) => (
              <li key={i}>
                {obj.name} - {obj.Age}  - {obj.gender} 

<br /><br />
<b>Name1</b>: <input type="text" className="form-control" name="name" value={this.state[obj.name]}  onChange={this.handleChange(obj.name)} /><br />

<b>Gender</b>: <input type="text" className="form-control" name="gender" value={this.state[obj.gender]}  onChange={this.handleChange(obj.gender)} />


              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey @jmarkatti, Have a look at this link you will understand it. https://codesandbox.io/s/wpzw0663w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to decide if you want your `input` to be controlled or not. Currently, you can't change value of your `input` because you have assigned a static value to it - `value={obj.name}`.

Your `onChange` handler is correct, however you will have to change the `value` of your `input`, from `value={obj.name}` to state-dependent, dynamic value.

```
handleChange = (name) => (event) => {
   this.setState({ [name]: event.target.value });
}
```

And the props in your input:

```
onChange={this.handleChange(obj.name)}
```

and

`value={this.state[obj.name]}`

Comment: Hi Sir Kind User, value={this.state.name} does not show name record. it only show a blank input that allows for editing and as you try to edit first record, all other records with name property gets edited as well. btw thanks for your help so far

Comment: Hi Sir Kind User, your solution is really good but it still show a blank input text for name and gender as the page load
 though i can now input data but showing black input form makes editing record very difficult since the record is no where to be found from 
the inputs. I have updated the post in the Updated Section to reflect how I implemented your solution. I also attached the screenshot to show how it displays blank input forms as the page loads. please Sir, can you help me further. between thanks for your venerable efforts and time so far. still counting and hoping on you.

Comment: @jmarkatti I would suggest you to pre-populate state in `componentDidMount` or inside the constructor, however its kinda complicated. The easiest way would be `value={this.state[obj.name] || 'name'}`

Comment: Thanks Sir Kind User